# Animation doesn't work on directive element repeated (ng-repeat) angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

i'm trying to implements animation on a element directive repeated with ng repeat :

```
<ven-activity class="animate" ng-click="selectActivity($index)"activite="activite" ng-repeat="activite in data.activites | filter :{hide:true}"></ven-activity>
```

I have followed a lot of tutorial or guide for that but until now it never worked. 
here is my css :

```
.animate { 
   ...
   ...
} 

.animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate.ng-enter {
    ...
    ...
}        

.animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.animate.ng-leave {
    .....


    .....
}
```

my headers :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->


    <script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Controllers/venActivityCtrl.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Directives/venActivity.js"></script>

  </head>
```

and my main module :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic-material','ngAnimate'])
```

I can't figure out why it won't work if anyone can help

thank you :)

Comment: Why dont you press f12 and check the console? Maybe there is something to guide you :)

Comment: The console talk about   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined in motion.js but i don't know what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a conflict in my script import between ionic and angular-animate. if ionic is used in the app there is no need to include neither angular nor angular-animate but still need to include the module in the app.